# Proving the set of $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous functions on $\Omega$ are dense on $C(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

The exercise: Let $\Omega$ be a compact Hausdorff metrizable space. Show that the subspace $C^{\alpha}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ of $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function is dense on $C(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$.

Now, a theorem I have at my disposal is:

> **(Stone-Weierstrass Theorem)** Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $S \subset C(X, \mathbb{R})$ obey:
>
> **i)** S is a subalgebra of $C(X, \mathbb{R})$, that is, $f, g \in S$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \implies f + g, fg, \lambda f \in S$
>
> **ii)** $S$ separates points , i.e, for each $x, y \in \Omega$ such that $x \neq y$, there exists $f \in C(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$
>
> **iii)** $\mathbb{1}$, the constant function $\equiv 1$ belongs to $S$
>
> then $\overline { S } ^ { \| \cdot \| _ { 0 } } = C ( \Omega , \mathbb { R } )$, i.e, $S$ is dense in $C(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$

My effort:

**i)** The only non-trivial part is showing that if $f, g$ are $\alpha$-Holder continuous then $fg$ as well. Indeed, we have:

\begin{align} \frac{|f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y)|}{d(x,y)^{\alpha}} &\leq \frac{|f(x)| |g(x) - g(y)|}{d(x,y)^{\alpha}}  + \frac{|g(y)||f(x) - f(y)|}{d(x,y)^{\alpha}} \\ &\leq \|f \| \text{Hol}_{\alpha}(g) + \|g \| \text{Hol}_{\alpha}(f)\end{align}

and then we're done because this implies $\text{Hol}_{\alpha}(fg)$ is finite, as desired.

**ii)** Let $x, y \in \Omega$ be given such that $x \neq y$. Then if we define $f_{x}(y) = d(x, y)^{\alpha}$ we have $0 = f_{x}(x) \neq f_{x}(y)$ because $x \neq y$. All that's left to show is that $\text{Hol}_{\alpha}(f_x)$ is finite. This is indeed the case because $\text{Hol}_{\alpha}(f_x) = 1$.

**iii)** This one is trivial because $\text{Hol}_{\alpha}(1) = 0$.

Is all of this correct? Is there something I could've done better? In case there's anything fundamentally wrong, a hint would really help!

Comment: Looks reasonable to me, for ii you could have also used $f_x(y) = d(x,y)$

Comment: Compact Hausdorff spaces need not be metrizable and Holder continuity does not make sense. You shoud say that $\Omega$ is a compact metric space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the list from which I took this exercise was not careful with that so I wasn't either, but you're completely right, I'll fix it. Otherwise, my proof is correct, right?